# Counterintuitive result, Expected Value of Uniform Random Variable raised to increasing powers.

Tags: probability, statistics

Out of curiosity, I've been playing with some simulations to simulate compounded interest rates from markets (such as stocks and cryptocurrencies).

Let $r \sim \mathcal{U}(0.90,1.05)$, be the return (as a percentage) of a single transaction. Let's say a stock was bought and sold, $r$ is the gain or loss for that particular transaction. I assumed a pessimistic distribution, $10\%$ loss and $5\%$ gain are the boundaries of the uniform distribution.

The expected value for a single transaction is $\mathbb{E}[r]=0.975$. I was curious to see the expected rate of return over multiple transactions, let's say $k$ transactions. This means I have to calculate $\mathbb{E}[r^k]$.

I do not know how to calculate $\mathbb{E}[r^k]$ manually and would appeciate if someone could teach me how. All I know is that it is not equal to $\mathbb{E}[r]^k$.

I used software to calculate $\mathbb{E}[r^k]$ for $k\in \{1,\dots,50\}$, and I was surprised by the result. I plotted the result below.

[image: Expected rate of return versus transaction number]

My intuition says that since $\mathbb{E}[r]=0.975$ then it is a losing game, and eventually would ruin the player, and indeed the plot shows increasing loss initially. However, I am baffled to see how it eventually became a positive rate of return.

I cannot explain this neither intuitively nor do I have enough mathematical background in this area to reason about it.

I appreciate your valuable insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Er^{k}=\frac  1{0.15} \int_{0.9}^{1.05} x^{k}dx=\frac  1 {0.15} \frac {(1.05)^{k+1} -(0.9)^{k+1}} {k+1}$.

Comment: A little bit of text would improve this answer immensly.